# I need to send input data from previous checkbox selection in a form and also php could not sent

Tags: php

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "daniel.galan.romano@gmail.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Mensaje de Grupo Monaco '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
        AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') 
    {
        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));
        die($output);
    } 

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing

    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) 
        || !isset($_POST["userRazonsocial"]) || !isset($_POST["userNombrefantasia"]) 
        || !isset($_POST["userCuit"]) || !isset($_POST["userDireccion"]) 
        || !isset($_POST["userLocalidad"]) || !isset($_POST["userProvincia"]) 
        || !isset($_POST["userTelefono"]) || !isset($_POST["userCelular"]) 
        || !isset($_POST["userClientes"]) || !isset($_POST["userSkype"]) 
        || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]) || !isset($_POST["userMarcas"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Hay campos vacios!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Razonsocial = filter_var($_POST["userRazonsocial"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Localidad    = filter_var($_POST["userLocalidad"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Cuit     = filter_var($_POST["userCuit"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Telefono    = filter_var($_POST["userTelefono"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Celular   = filter_var($_POST["userCelular"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Provincia    = filter_var($_POST["userProvincia"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Direccion    = filter_var($_POST["userDireccion"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Marcas     = filter_var($_POST["userMarcas"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Skype    = filter_var($_POST["userSkype"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Nombrefantasia    = filter_var($_POST["userNombrefantasia"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Clientes   = filter_var($_POST["userClientes"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $user_Message = str_replace("\&#39;", "'", $user_Message);
    $user_Message = str_replace("&#39;", "'", $user_Message);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Nombre muy corto o vacio!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor ingrese un email valido!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Mensaje muy corto!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message . "\r\n\n"  .'-- '.$user_Name. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Email . "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Clientes. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Localidad. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Provincia. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Marcas. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Cuit. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Telefono. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Celular. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Direccion. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Skype. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Nombrefantasia. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Razonsocial, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hola '.$user_Name .'! Gracias por enviarnos sus datos, lo contactaremos a la brevedad asignandole la contraseña para poder ingresar en el archivo excel para acceder a nuestra lista de precios que podra descargar desde esta misma web.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

This is the php and the html

```
<form class="form contact-form" id="contact_form">
    <div class="clearfix">Nombre de contacto:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Nombre de contacto:*" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
        </div>
        Razón Social:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="razonsocial" id="razonsocial" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Razón social:" pattern=".{3,100}">
        </div>
        Nombre de fantasía:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="nombrefantasia" id="nombrefantasia" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Nombre de fantasía:" pattern=".{3,100}">
        </div>
        Cuit:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="cuit" id="cuit" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Cuit:" pattern=".{3,100}">
        </div>
        Dirección:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Dirección:*" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
        </div>
        Localidad:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="localidad" id="localidad" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Localidad:*" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
        </div>
        Provincia:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Provincia:*" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
        </div>
        Teléfono:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Teléfono:*" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
        </div>
        Celular:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="celular" id="celular" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Celular:*" pattern=".{3,100}" required>
        </div>
        Skype:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="skype" id="skype" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Skype:" pattern=".{3,100}">
        </div>
        Email:
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="marcas" id="marcas" class="input-md round form-control" placeholder="Email:*" pattern=".{5,100}" required>
        </div>
        Conoce alguna de nuestras marcas?(Si la respuesta es "si",  indique cual)
        SI<input type="checkbox" name="-" onclick="dynInput(this);" />
        NO<input type="checkbox" name="check2" />
        <p id="insertinputs"></p>

        <div class="form-group">
            Tipo de Cliente: 
            <select class="input-md round form-control" id="clientes" name="clientes">
                <option value="volvo">Publico</option>
                <option value="saab">Retail</option>
                <option value="opel">Distribuidor</option>
            </select>
        </div>                                      
        Comentarios:
            <div class="form-group">                                            
                <textarea name="message" id="message" class="input-md round form-control" style="height: 84px;" placeholder="Comentarios"></textarea>
            </div>

         </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <!-- Inform Tip -->                                        
            <div class="form-tip pt-20">
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> * los campos son obligatorios
            </div>

            <!-- Send Button -->
            <div class="align-right pt-10">
                <button class="submit_btn btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round" id="submit_btn">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
```

UPDATE

I put this

```
$sanitizedEmail = filter_var($visitormail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 
mail(' no-reply@grupomonaco.ferozo.com', $subject, $message, 'From: ' . $sanitizedEmail);
```

that is the email from the server but still not working

Comment: And what is your question? Is there any error message involved?

Comment: @NicoHaase the error are 2
1 - "email couldnt sent please check your php mail configuration"
2 - some inputs are empty

Comment: Dan if you want us to help at least attempt to format your code dump so it is readable. Help us to help you

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, sorry Riggs you are right. I spent like 20m to indent the code correctly but sometimes it appear a new error. I think now its ok

Comment: **NOW** Compare your `name="..."` attributes on your HTML with the `$_POST` names you have used!!?!?!

Comment: **THEN** Add a `method="POST"` to your `<form>` tag

Comment: @RiggsFolly done! now the error is "Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration."

Comment: DID YOU do as it suggested and check the mail server? 1) Do you have one> 2) Does PHP know about it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using a hosting linux that allows php contact forms but this is not working. It seems that i have to use SMTP protocol due spammers. But because my site is a boostrap template and not a wordpress/joomla i dont know how to set it

Comment: First try sending FROM an email address that exists on your hosting account. Hosts now normally insist you send from a real email address they can actually verify. This stops  the Open Relay issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly I put this
    $sanitizedEmail = filter_var($visitormail, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
mail(' no-reply@grupomonaco.ferozo.com', $subject, $message, 'From: ' . $sanitizedEmail);

that is the email from the server but still not working..

Comment: Not working with the same error?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes!

Comment: Try removing the space before the email address

Comment: And you are still using the VISITORS email as the FROM address. That should be a valid/existing Email account that exists on your hosting email server

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, that is the email my hosting gave it to me..

Comment: Reverse the emails like this `mail($sanitizedEmail, $subject, $message, 'From: ' . ' no-reply@grupomonaco.ferozo.com');`

Comment: [Look at the manual for where the FROM and TO addresses go](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly its working!! how I can put your answer as correct?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks riggs! have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try sending FROM an email address that exists on your hosting account. Hosts now normally insist you send from a real email address they can actually verify. This stops the Open Relay issue

Then reverse the email addresses like this as you are using the FROM address as the TO address and vise versa.

```
mail($sanitizedEmail, $subject, $message, 'From: ' . ' no-reply@grupomonaco.ferozo.com');
```